# How to edit HTML files with Word VBA XMLHTTP object

Tags: html, vba, xmlhttprequest, ms-word

I'm writing a Word VBA macro that ultimately creates a HTML file equivalent. After this HTML file is created, I want to put it's bare HTML code in a string for further editing (in the same macro script). All my files I'm dealing with are accessed with HTTP requests to a local server, not to a local drive. 
Here's some code I have:

```
...{other code}...
Dim httpreq as Object
Dim htmlread as String
Set httpreq = CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTP")
...{other code}...
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName := HTMLFilePath, FileFormat: wdFormatFilteredHTML
httpreq.Open "POST", HTMLFilePath, False
httpreq.send
htmlread = httpreq.responseText

..{htmlread string is modified using VBA methods like Replace}...
```

How do I overwrite HTMLFilePath file with modified string using HTTP methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For latest versions of MS Office you can use `Microsoft XML, v 6.0` and `Microsoft HTML Object Library`

In VBA window, select `Tools -> References -> Microsoft XML, v 6.0` and 
`Tools -> References -> Microsoft HTML Object Library`

Try the following code:

```
Sub parse()
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim htmlread As String

With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.google.com", False
    .send
    htmlread = .responseText
End With

html.body.innerHTML = htmlread 'raw full source code
Debug.Print html.body.innerHTML

'..{htmlread string is modified using VBA methods like Replace}...

html.body.innerHTML = htmlread 'edited source code
Debug.Print html.body.innerHTML

Set html = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, and also how do I upload/save the updated document to the actual document on the server?

Comment: @Steven if you are going to save it in local drive you can save it as html file like `ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=path FileFormat:=xlHtml` But it is not that simple. I am not professional about this but any images, CSS files, other attachments etc. also should be saved. However there is no need to do that if you are going to upload it to server. You can [transfer the file to server though FTP](https://officetricks.com/ftp-server-file-transfer-with-excel-macro/) to the best of my knowledge.